# jEditable - Unable to do validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable, edit-in-place

Alright. I'm new to jEditable. I wanna use jQuery validation with jEditable. Let me explain. Here, i'm echoing a table from my database in a while loop something like this.

```
<table id="example" class="display"  cellspacing="0" border="0">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
    Name
    </th>
    <th>
    Phone
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="items" userid="'.$row['id'].'" id="name">'.$row['name'].'</td>
    <td class="items" userid="'.$row['id'].'" id="name">'.$row['email'].'</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the jEditable script i'm using

```
$(function() {
$("td.items").each(function(index) {    
$(this).editable("handler.php", { 
submitdata : {userid: $(this).attr('userid')},
indicator : "<img src='images/indicator.gif'>",
tooltip   : "Doubleclick to edit...",
event     : "dblclick",
onblur    : "submit",
name : 'newvalue',
id   : 'elementid',

});
});
```

The jEditable is working. Its awesome. I just want to use jQuery validation codes. Where do i put them?

Answer (score 0):

The painful experience of using jEditable is : very hard to integrate with other-validation plugins, such as really_simple_validation.  so I don't think it's very easy for your to write simple and clean code to do that. maybe you could see its call back functions?